# Angular variable are not refreshing on page when fetching data from google script

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script

Doing one Google Script APP. With server side method that returns array of string.
`getClassRoomList()`.

Can you please suggest what is wrong with my current HTML? As the success handler is running all well on response. But the ng variable message is not reflecting on page; while the jQuery does populate the table.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="myApp">
            <head>
                <base target="_top">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
                <script>
                    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
                    app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
                    $scope.message = [];
                    $scope.populateTable = function(array){
                        //Setting ng variable; but the page doesn't show anything
                        $scope.message = array;

                        //Setting the Table by JQuery; it does work.
                        var table = $('#myTable');
                        table.empty();
                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            var item = '<tr><td><div class="classname">' + array[i] +'</div></td></tr>';
                            table.append(item);
                        }
                    };
                    $scope.mainClick = function(){
                        $scope.message = $scope.message + 'chirag';
                        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler($scope.populateTable).getClassRoomList();
                    };
                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
                <button ng-click="mainClick()">Proceed</button>
                <table id="myTable"></table>
                <div ng-bind="message"></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. When the button was clicked, did you confirm whether ``getClassRoomList()`` was run? 2. About your current HTML, the current HTML in the question is the whole script you are using? If it is not whole script, can you provide the whole one?

Comment: If the script in your question is the whole script, how about adding a tag like ``<html ng-app="myApp">...</html>``? Or how about modifying from ``<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">`` to ``<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-app="myApp">``? ``ng-app`` means the root element. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp But I'm not sure how you are running your HTML. So if I this was not the direct solution, can you provide more information?

Comment: 1) Yes button click does execute the JScript and so Tabel is getting populated. Also the message variable does hold the correct array value; but it is not getting displayed. If I click for second time it does display the value of message on page.

Comment: I re-editaed the Code; please review again. I am new to stackOverFlow so was not able to put whole code before.

Comment: If i just return the hard-coded array/text, instead of calling the google script; then it is showing correct values on button click. Issue happens only when are trying to get something from google script function.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, for example, how about updating bindings? So how about modifying from ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler($scope.populateTable).getClassRoomList();`` to ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e) => {$scope.populateTable(e); $scope.$apply();}).getClassRoomList();``?

Comment: This works. Thanks. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e) => {$scope.populateTable(e); $scope.$apply();}).getClassRoomList();`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Can you post the solution as an answer and accept it? By this, I think that it will help other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Thanks. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e) => {$scope.populateTable(e); $scope.$apply();}).getClassRoomList();`